# Can't convert `.bin` file into `.iso` format with the command `bchunk`

Tags: iso, format-conversion

I have `.bin` & `.cue` movie file ready for burning, and I'm trying to convert it into the `.iso` file format using `bchunk`.

My problem is that it gives me `.ugh` file format instead of `.iso` as a result as seen in the picture

[image]

P. S: My OS is Ubuntu 12. 04 with a 64 bit architecture.

Answer (score 1):

type `bchunk IMAGE.bin IMAGE.cue IMAGE.iso`

Changing IMAGE for the right directory and filename